# Sorting an array of alphanumeric strings

Tags: list, dart, sorting, comparator

I want to sort a list of names(not precisely names but alphanumeric strings) such that all names that start with a digit go to end of list and are sorted individually. While all names that start with an English alphabet come to the start of list and are individually sorted. Case sensitivity does not matter e.g 'Apple' is treated same as 'appLE'.

I tried the following code

```
void main() {
  List<String> names = ['782Agh1', 'Umas', 'apple', 'John', '32'];

  names.sort((String name1, String name2) {
    bool n1StartsWithDigit = name1.startsWith(RegExp(r'[0-9]'));
    bool n2StartsWithDigit = name2.startsWith(RegExp(r'[0-9]'));

    if (!n1StartsWithDigit && !n2StartsWithDigit) {
      //If both names do not start with a digit
      return name1.toLowerCase().compareTo(name2.toLowerCase());
    }
    //Cases when one name starts with a digit and other does not
    if (n1StartsWithDigit && !n2StartsWithDigit) {
      return name2.compareTo(name1);
    }
    if (!n1StartsWithDigit && n2StartsWithDigit) {
      return name1.compareTo(name2);
    }
    //Both names start with digit
    return name1.compareTo(name2);
  });

  print(names);
}
```

and my expected outcome is [apple, John, Umas, 32, 782Agh1]

Comment: How does your code's output differ from what is expected?

Comment: My code output is [32, apple, John, Umas, 782Agh1]

Comment: If one starts with a digit and the other does not, you shouldn't need to do any comparing.

Comment: if (n1StartsWithDigit && !n2StartsWithDigit) {
      return 1;
    }
    if (!n1StartsWithDigit && n2StartsWithDigit) {
      return -1;
    }

I modified the following two conditions and now it gives correct results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should do the trick. See comments in the code for explanation

```
void main() {
  List<String> names = ['782Agh1', 'Umas', 'apple', 'John', '32'];
   
  
  names.sort((String a, String b) {
    //determines wheter a or b start with a digit
    bool ad = a.startsWith(RegExp(r'[0-9]'));
    bool bd = b.startsWith(RegExp(r'[0-9]'));  
    
    // ^ is the XOR operator, which returns true if one is true and the other false
    if (ad^bd) {
      //so one string starts with a digit, the other not
      //if a starts with a digit, it has to be sorted after b => return 1
      //if b starts with a digit, it has to be sorted after a => return -1
      return ad ? 1 : -1;
    }
    
    //both start either with a digit or a alphabetic character
    //compare them as usual
    return a.toLowerCase().compareTo(b.toLowerCase());
  });
  
  print(names);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, the "starts with digit" code is not particularly efficient. Here is a, possibly, more efficient version:

```dart
bool _startsWithDigit(String string) => 
    string.isNotEmpty && string.codeUnitAt(0) ^ 0x30 <= 9;

// Ignores case of ASCII letters in strings.
int _compareIgnoreAsciiCase(String a, String b) {
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length && i < b.length; i++) {
    var ca = a.codeUnitAt(i);
    var cb = a.codeUnitAt(i);
    var delta = ca ^ cb;
    if (delta == 0) continue;
    if (delta == 0x20) {
      var uca = ca | 0x20; // Upper case if letter.
      if (0x61 <= uca && uca <= 0x7A) continue;
    }
    return ca - cb;
  }
  return a.length - b.length;
}

int compareWithNumbersLast(String a, String b) {
  var da = _startsWithDigit(a); // A starts with digit?
  var db = _startsWithDigit(b); // B starts with digit?
  if (da) {
    if (!db) return 1;
  } else if (db) {
    return -1;
  } 
  return _compareIgnoreAsciiCase(a, b);
}
```